# Facebook URL share shows 502 bad gateway

Tags: facebook

I've been trying to understand the cause of this problem still no luck.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.helpbit.com%2F

Facebook debugger shows 502 but same thing I checked with facebook api & there was no error, moreover I've verified there is no error on site, I checked console & network. I even checked google+ & preview is working fine with google+

[image]

Here is a screen of my og tags

[image]

Comment: Debug your server and see why it returns 502.

Comment: Do you think it has something to do with IPV-6

Comment: Maybe. Probably easier to just debug your server than having a guessing contest

Comment: @WizKid thanks, forwarded this to devOps, really appreciate